# Why doesn't llvm-config on Windows emit the correct parameters for clang++.exe?

Tags: windows, llvm, clang++, llvm-clang, ghdl

I'm no experienced LLVM user, but I'm trying to compile a Linux LLVM project on Windows. The project is GHDL.

Because ready-to-use LLVM installers for Windows don't have `llvm-config` bundled, I needed to compile LLVM and clange from sources. The project requires LLVM 3.5.

So first, I downloaded `llvm-3.5.2` and `clang-3.5.2` and used CMake to translate it into Visual Studio 2013 projects. Then I used VS2013 to compile it.

The original makefile calls `llvm-config`. The resulting string is passed to `clang++`:

```
clang++ -c -I`/usr/lib/llvm-3.5/bin/llvm-config --includedir --cflags --cxxflags` -o llvm-cbindings.o src/ortho/llvm/llvm-cbindings.cpp
```

I'm using PowerShell to call `llvm-config` and store the result in a variable:

```
$LLVM_CONFIG_RESULT = & $LLVM_CONFIG --cxxflags
```

The result is:

```
-IC:\Tools\LLVM-3.5/include  /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3     /MP -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE -D_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_WARNINGS -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -wd4146 -wd4180 -wd4244 -wd4267 -wd4291 -wd4345 -wd4351 -wd4355 -wd4503 -wd4624 -wd4722 -wd4800 -w14062 -we4238 -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS
```

I notice several problems:

1. Some paths have `/` instead of `\`
   `-IC:\Tools\LLVM-3.5/include`
2. Some switches and parameters are used with `-` others with `/`
   `... -IC:\Tools\LLVM-3.5/include  /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS ...`
3. Some parameters are delimited by more then one space sign
   `... /W3     /MP ...`
4. clang++.exe prints errors on unknown arguments:

   > clang++.exe: error: unknown argument: '-wd4146'
   >   clang++.exe: error: unknown argument: '-wd4180'
   >   clang++.exe: error: unknown argument: '-wd4244'
   >   clang++.exe: error: unknown argument: '-wd4267'
   >   clang++.exe: error: unknown argument: '-wd4291'
   >   clang++.exe: error: unknown argument: '-wd4345'
   >   clang++.exe: error: unknown argument: '-wd4351'
   >   clang++.exe: error: unknown argument: '-wd4355'
   >   clang++.exe: error: unknown argument: '-wd4503'
   >   clang++.exe: error: unknown argument: '-wd4624'
   >   clang++.exe: error: unknown argument: '-wd4722'
   >   clang++.exe: error: unknown argument: '-wd4800'
   >   clang++.exe: error: unknown argument: '-w14062'
   >   clang++.exe: error: unknown argument: '-we4238'

The result is now included into the clang++.exe call, which causes errors.

```
Command: 'C:\Tools\LLVM-3.5\bin\clang++.exe -c -c -v -IC:\Tools\LLVM-3.5/include  /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3     /MP -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE -D_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_WARNINGS -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -wd4146 -wd4180 -wd4244 -wd4267 -wd4291 -wd4345 -wd4351 -wd4355 -wd4503 -wd4624 -wd4722 -wd4800 -w14062 -we4238 -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -o llvm-cbindings.o ../../src\ortho\llvm\llvm-bindings.cpp -o llvm-cbindings.o ../../src\ortho\llvm\llvm-cbindings.cpp'  
clang++.exe: error: unknown argument: '-wd4146'  
clang++.exe: error: unknown argument: '-wd4180'  
clang++.exe: error: unknown argument: '-wd4244'  
clang++.exe: error: unknown argument: '-wd4267'  
clang++.exe: error: unknown argument: '-wd4291'  
clang++.exe: error: unknown argument: '-wd4345'  
clang++.exe: error: unknown argument: '-wd4351'  
clang++.exe: error: unknown argument: '-wd4355'  
clang++.exe: error: unknown argument: '-wd4503'  
clang++.exe: error: unknown argument: '-wd4624'  
clang++.exe: error: unknown argument: '-wd4722'  
clang++.exe: error: unknown argument: '-wd4800'  
clang++.exe: error: unknown argument: '-w14062'  
clang++.exe: error: unknown argument: '-we4238'  
clang version 3.5.2 (tags/RELEASE_352/final)  
Target: i686-pc-windows-msvc  
Thread model: posix  
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: '/DWIN32'  
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: '/D_WINDOWS'  
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: '/W3'  
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: '/MP'
```

**So here are my questions:**

- Why does `llvm-config` emit false results on Windows?
- How can I fix it?
- What are these `-wd***` switches for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why does llvm-config emit false results on Windows?
>
> How can I fix it?

It does not. llvm-config gives you the right arguments but you use the wrong frontend for Windows. clang++ is build for platforms that originally have a GNU compiler tool-chain (g++ etc.). The Windows frontend (clang-cl) is a replacement for the Visual Studio tool-chain and accepts the values provided by llvm-config.

From your usecase calling `clang++` results in:

```
PS C:\Users\XXX> clang++ -wd4146
clang++.exe: error: unknown argument: '-wd4146'
clang++.exe: error: no input files
```

while calling `clang-cl`:

```
PS C:\Users\XXX> clang-cl -wd4146
clang-cl.exe: error: no input files
```

works as intended. This is because the GNU and the Visual Studio tool-chains have different command line flags for the frontend. This leads to your last question:

> What are these -wd*** switches for?

With -wd*** switches you disable specific compiler warnings for example 4146 is documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/4kh09110%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

```
C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned
```

Comment: I think you should name it "Visual Studio tool-chain" instead of "Windows tool-chain".

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still in struggle, there is a way to get clang working with llvm-config within the Powershell:

```sh
> clang $($(llvm-config --cxxflags).split())
```

For some reason the llvm-config output without splitting is counted as a single big argument by clang.